# how to do i set bulk usb transfer rate

Tags: usb, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi with Ubuntu 20.04 (installed from the image `ubuntu-20.04.3-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img`).

I want to set the bulk USB transfer rate to 150.

---

Here is how I do it on Raspberry Pi OS:

- Open `/etc/rc.local` with an editor.
- Add the following line at the end of the file before `exit 0`:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 150 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb'
```

- Save & Close the file and reboot the system.

---

How do I do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?  20.04 has the same file, with a default contents of 16, so maybe the same command will work.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS I see as just a *respun/tweaked* Debian, however you provided no release info on that. Most everything possible in Debian is the same with Ubuntu where the version details match up - details you've not provided. Also note they don't always match up, eg. my Ubuntu *jammy* differs to my Debian *bookworm* with Ubuntu ahead in some areas; but ~equal in a large proportion. What releases are you asking about???

Answer (score 0):

Use the systemd start up service instead
it actually says rc.local is no longer running upon boot up on Raspberry Pi4

so create a file like this

sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/usb_bulk_transfer_rate.service

write this for example

[Unit]
Description=set usb bulk transfer rate
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/cams/src/acp/sonyCam/write_bulk_transfer_usb.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

then write this in the python file (or what ever you prefer to use)
cd /home/pi/cams/src/acp/sonyCam
sudo vi write_bulk_transfer_usb.py

with open("/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb", "w") as f:
print("150", file=f)
f.close()

then start the service as follows

sudo systemctl enable usb_bulk_transfer_rate.service
sudo systemctl start usb_bulk_transfer_rate.service
sudo systemctl status usb_bulk_transfer_rate.service

check success by looking for 150 returned from the command

pi@CameraPi:~/cams/src/acp/sonyCam $ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb
150

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion.

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/usbfs_memory_mb.service`

Contents of the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=raise usbfs memory mb for sdrs and frigate
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=sudo sh -c 'echo 150 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now enable it to execute on startup

`sudo systemctl enable usbfs_memory_mb.service`

Now it's running on every startup.

As a bonus just so you're aware, you can run it as a one-off anytime.

`sudo systemctl start usbfs_memory_mb.service`